# float elements right and left independent size css

Tags: html, css

Just trying to do something like left and right floating, but independent of the height...

Here is my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bta5Q/) the problem in this example 2 and 4 aren't near seems like have a space. Not sure how the best way to implement and without having issues in different browser (only was testing in chrome)

Thanks

Comment: You are pointing to horizontal space or vertical space?

Comment: the space between 2 and 4.. vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

Put the "float left" elements in one container, and the "float right" elements in another. Then float the containers instead of the elements.